# How can I find Hexo local host?

Tags: localhost, hexo

I launched a local server at my PC with hexo server command, but I did not get my website address. localhost:4000 does not work at all. Instead of that I got some strange and useless information:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Hexo>hexo server
Usage: hexo <command>

Commands:
  help     Get help on a command.
  init     Create a new Hexo folder.
  version  Display version information.

Global Options:
  --config  Specify config file instead of using _config.yml
  --cwd     Specify the CWD
  --debug   Display all verbose messages in the terminal
  --draft   Display draft posts
  --safe    Disable all plugins and scripts
  --silent  Hide output on console
```

Then, I tried "npm install hexo-server --save", and "hexo server" again, but in vain. How can I find the localhost address?

Answer (score 0):

You should first init a hexo project in current folder.

If you run `hexo` in a folder without hexo project files, it will show you those message.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using hexo for the first time,

1. You should create a folder to store your website source code
2. use your command line tool to enter the folder
3. run the command `hexo init` to generate your website source code
4. and then you can use `hexo server` to see your website address "localhost:4000"